# W 8.1 async method and navigation c# xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, async-await, windows-8.1

I'm trying to navigate to a page after the user click a button to download a file. The download method is async so the app wait until the method end and then navigate to the page.

Code:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     await vm.DownloadFile(id);
     this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```

I want to navigate to the page before the method end. How can i do this or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: And what problems are you having with the code that you've posted?

Comment: the application does not perform the page change until the file is downloaded, the code shows how to call the function for downloading and then navigate. I dont know if i need to do the call to the method and navigation in other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to navigate before the download has completed, simply don't `await` for the download to complete before navigating:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     vm.DownloadFile(id);
     this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```

Comment: @kentenz That depends entirely on how its implemented.  I doubt it uses any thread at all to do its work; IO generally has little (if any) need for CPU bound work, and thus doesn't need a thread at all.

Comment: thanks, i thought that async-await was similar to threads and workers but after reading some post i realize that they aren't similar. Calling a async method without await isn't a bad practice? Or that depends on how its implemented?

Comment: @kentenz If you want to do something after it completes, it of course won't work.  If you honestly don't care when it finishes and have nothing to do when it ends, then you don't `await` it.  Such situations are of course going to be unusual.

Comment: I'm trying to download a file and navigate to main page. In the main page is displayed the status of the download. Would be a better approach sends data through a parameter on the navigation and check the data on main page loadState to start the download? @Servy

Comment: @rod256 If you want to do something on the main page with the result of this operation, it'll need to get access to this `Task` somehow, yes.

Comment: @Servy No, just to avoid call the method without await in the download page. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try Using This code it's the same but remove await

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     vm.DownloadFile(id);
     this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```